# Scala RDD with pattern matching from a text file

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, rdd

***kinda new to Spark***. So here's the problem, I have a txt file with some general format, lets say: `Time` `:` `Message`  So i have to implement two things: RDD and pattern groups and matching.

To take the file as an rdd:

```
val rdd1 = sc.textFile(location)
```

To Build the pattern:

```
private val f1 = "([0-9]*)"
private val f2 = "([:])"
private val f3 = "(.*?)"
private val regex = s"$f1 $f2 $f3"
private val p = Pattern.compile(regex)
```

now i want to integrate both of these,

```
rdd1.map(//What to do here)
```

I want to check each line if it matches the general format.If it doesn't i want to display an error message for each line that doesn't match.

if it does match, i wanna make groups for the pattern stated above. f1 is group1, f2 is group2, f3 is group three.Finally i wanna search f3(message field) for keywords like error,failure.

I know this is a lot to ask for.Thx in advance.

What i have already tried:

```
def parseLine(s1: String): Option[Groups] = {
val matcher = p.matcher(s1)
if (matcher.find) {
  println("General Format correct")
  //group
  Some(group(matcher))
  //after format is verified search f3 for error,failure keyword.

}
else {
  println("Format Wrong")
  None
}
}

def group(matcher: Matcher) = {
Line(
  matcher.group(1),
  matcher.group(2),
  matcher.group(3))}

case class Line(Time: String, colon: String, Message: String)
```

Now i am stuck on how to iterate the rdd to pass each line of the text file to the function.if i pass the entire rdd to the function ie, RDD[String] type.Other elements like matcher doesn't work cause it expects String type.
While reading about the rdd functions:(correct me if i am wrong), the foreach method should iterate the rdd but i get type mismatches. currently trying the map function but havn't got it yet.

As i said i am new to spark rdd's.I don't know if using partition function would help me out instead of grouping.

I really need some guidance from the experianced. Any help is appriciated.

Comment: "I want to check each line if it matches the general format.I" This is not related to Spark. What have you tried? " i wanna make groups for the pattern stated above" What do you mean by "make groups"? What will you do with the group? " i wanna search " ... and then what? (and please don't use "I wanna", it makes you sound like you're in kindergarten)

Comment: "The main abstraction Spark provides is a resilient distributed dataset (RDD), which is a collection of elements partitioned across the nodes of the cluster that can be operated on in parallel."                                       I have used it in the first line of code for the text file. ok i'll be more specific on what i have tried.

Comment: `map` is the function you want. From your code, it looks like `rdd1.map(parseLine(_))` should work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With simple examples like this, often the way you'd do it with an RDD is the same as how you'd do it with a simple Scala sequence. If we take Spark out of the equation, an approach would be:

```
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

val input = List(
  "123 : Message1 Error",
  "This line doesn't conform",
  "345 : Message2",
  "Neither does this one",
  "789 : Message3 Error"
)

val f1 = "([0-9]*)"
val f2 = "([:])"
val f3 = "(.*)"
val regex = s"$f1 $f2 $f3".r

case class Line(a: String, b: String, c: String)


//Use Success and Failure as the functional way of representing
//operations which might not succeed
val parsed = input.map { str =>
  regex.findFirstMatchIn(str).map(m => Line(m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3))) match {
    case Some(l) => Success(l)
    case None => Failure(new Exception(s"Non matching input: $str"))
  }
}

//Now split the parsed result so we can handle the two types of outcome separately
val matching = parsed.filter(_.isSuccess)
val nonMatching = parsed.filter(_.isFailure)

nonMatching.foreach(println)

//Filter for only those messages we're interested in
val messagesWithError = matching.collect{
  case Success(l @ Line(_,_,m)) if m.contains("Error") => l
}

messagesWithError.foreach(println)
```

What's different when we do it in Spark? Not much:

```
  val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Example"))

  import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

  val input = List(
    "123 : Message1 Error",
    "This line doesn't conform",
    "345 : Message2",
    "Neither does this one",
    "789 : Message3 Error"
  )

  val f1 = "([0-9]*)"
  val f2 = "([:])"
  val f3 = "(.*)"
  val regex = s"$f1 $f2 $f3".r

  case class Line(a: String, b: String, c: String)

  val inputRDD = sc.parallelize(input)

  //Use Success and Failure as the functional way of representing
  //operations which might not succeed
  val parsedRDD = inputRDD.map { str =>
    regex.findFirstMatchIn(str).map(m => Line(m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3))) match {
      case Some(l) => Success(l)
      case None => Failure(new Exception(s"Non matching input: $str"))
    }
  }

  //Now split the parsed result so we can handle the two types of outcome separately
  val matchingRDD = parsedRDD.filter(_.isSuccess)
  val nonMatchingRDD = parsedRDD.filter(_.isFailure)

  //We use collect() to bring the results back from the Spark workers to the Driver
  nonMatchingRDD.collect().foreach(println)

  //Filter for only those messages we're interested in
  val messagesWithError = matchingRDD.collect {
    case Success(l@Line(_, _, m)) if m.contains("Error") => l
  }

  //We use collect() to bring the results back from the Spark workers to the Driver
  messagesWithError.collect().foreach(println)
}
```

If the resulting data sets were very large, using `collect()` to bring the results to the driver would not be appropriate, but neither would the use of `println` to log the results.

Comment: Thank you for your reply